# How do you check if a variable is defined inside a module in Julia?

Tags: julia

`isdefined(:x)` will tell you if a variable x is defined in your current workspace.

If I want to check a variable is defined in a module (not one that's exported), how can I do that? I tried all of the following:

```
julia> module Test
       x = 1
       end
Test

julia> x
ERROR: UndefVarError: x not defined

julia> isdefined(:x)
false

julia> Test.x
1

julia> isdefined(:Test.x)
ERROR: type Symbol has no field x

julia> isdefined(:Test.:x)
ERROR: TypeError: getfield: expected Symbol, got QuoteNode

julia> isdefined(Test.:x)
ERROR: TypeError: getfield: expected Symbol, got QuoteNode
```

In the module Test above, I want to check if x is defined or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`isdefined` has an optional parameter for doing this. Try:

```
isdefined(Test, :x)
```

More information available through the usual channels: `?isdefined` on the REPL and in the book: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/base/#Base.isdefined (link may be for older version, so the currently dominant search engine will help).

Answer (score 5):

I think you need

```
:x in names(Test)
```

Comment: Or `isdefined(Test, :x)`. There is an optinal parameter to `isdefined`.

Comment: @DanGetz your comment is correct, could you post it as an answer?

Comment: I'll give it to the @DanGetz answer as slightly more compact, but it was quite useful to know about names(Module) as well. Thanks!!

Comment: This solution now fails for me in Julia 0.6.3, it returns false whether the name is in the module or not.

Answer (score 2):

In Julia 1.1.0, isdefined's first parameter is not optional, instead there is a macro `@isdefined(x)` or `@isdefined x` that tests if x is defined. Calling it inside Test, checks if x is defined when in Test (inherited or not).

See [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@isdefined).